# SSL certificate for local and outer IP

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have no background in IT and networking, so this might be kind of stupid but...

I have an SCADA app running on Windows 10, and the app has has it's own website configured.
It has security certificate for the local IP issued. And everything is fine up to this point.

But to access the site from somewhere else we are port forwarding requests from our outer IP to the local address so now the IP doesn't match the one in certificate and it is not working.
What would be the right workaround in these situations, I can't get my head around this problem.
I can issue certificate to the outer ip, but then local network certificates are not working.

Thank you!

Comment: Please ask on superuser.com or serverfault.com, stackoverflow.com is a platform for programming questions.

Comment: whoops, ok, thank you!